# Can I turn off Predictive Input for EditField?

Tags: blackberry

I understand 'Predictive Input' option can be helpful for texting and email but I want my app to turn off this option programmatically for EditFields for username and password. How can I accomplish this?

Edit: Noticed PasswordEditField has a side effect that it doesn't do any transformation (no auto replacement, no autocaps, no autotext). That's what I am looking for. Then can I somehow defeat its default action that replaces entered text with a string of asterisks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to provide the `TextField.NO_COMPLEX_INPUT` style to your field: [Disabling word suggestion / AutoText / SureType in a particular EditField](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Disabling-word-suggestion-AutoText-SureType-in-a-particular/td-p/378041)