# Predictive Input turned off but still word suggestion box pops up

Tags: blackberry

I could [turn off Predictive Input by NO_COMPLEX_INPUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341482/can-i-turn-off-predictive-input-for-editfield). So while I am typing into EditField, no transformation kicks in. Happy about that.
But still word suggestion box pops up when I type in "bo" and click Trackpad. How can I prevent this?

I noticed right after I typed 'o', dotted line appears under the "bo" which probably indicates it has some suggestion, then suggestion box appears on click. Also when suggestion box appeared, trackwheelClick() is not being called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found NON_SPELLCHECKABLE prevents word suggestion:

```
editUsername = new EditField("" , "", 25, EditField.NON_SPELLCHECKABLE | EditField.NO_COMPLEX_INPUT);
```